# Finding POI/business directory data to import

Tags: database, api, google-places-api, yellow-pages

I'm creating an app, and I need a basic business directory data per city such as restaurant's name, address, and phone#, and import it into my database.

Anyone knows where I can do that?

Is there anything like it that's free? 
maybe not too expensive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to import it to your database? Why not just send a request to [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) when the user requests the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two ways are compile it yourself for free from the resources below, but it would be time consuming and very resource intensive:

---

Yellow Pages Directory

White Pages Directory

IRS Records

Company Registration Records

---

I found two commercial resources, 
This one claims 20 million business for $80 http://www.usadatabase.info/features.html and http://leads.infousa.com/USBusinesses.aspx?bas_vendor=190000 requires a signup to access there pricing and database information.  There may be other resources less expensive or better, but these seemed like something you can compare against.  If you don't need a static database the suggestions of using the google places api seem the best.

Comment: Yea I guess I could use google api, and slowly loading it up to my database. That seems to be the best apporach for me so far. Thanks